# What is the quickest way of resetting Pokemon's EV in Pokemon Sun and Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I was wondering what is the quickest way I can reset my Pokemon's own EV so I can help EV train my Pokemon. The only thing I could do is grow friendship raising berries that can also lower the EVs of certain stats and I was hoping to find a faster way of resetting EVs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the Berry method that has been around for a while, [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5dx4nh/psa_resetting_evs_in_sunmoon/) discusses using the Festival Plaza's Friendship Parlor and Friendship Cafe to reset EVs.

> In Festival Plaza, you can obtain two stalls called Friendship Parlor and Friendship Cafe. At 2 stars, you have the ability to purchase EV reducing meals:
>
> - Hp, Atk, Def @ Friendship Parlor
> - Sp. Atk, Sp. Def, Speed @ Friendship Cafe
>
> These significantly reduce EVs for those stats and can be purchased once per day. The kicker is as follows: they cannot be used on Pokemon with maxed out friendship, or Pokemon that are fainted. You can reduce friendship by having your Pokemon faint and then reviving them from a Pokemon Center, or by using Herbal Medicine (available for purchase on the second city of the second island).

However, as this can only be used once a day and only on Pokemon without maximum friendship, berries could be quicker, as it is entirely possible to get the required 11 berries to reset a stat's EVs from a single tree's yield. (maximum yield is 14 berries according to the linked thread)

---

Either way, there is no quick and easy way to reset EVs like the Reset Bag in Gen 6, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the fastest way to reset EVs are the Secret Meals available from Friendship Cafés and Friendship Parlors in the Festival Plaza: they immediately drop a stat back to 0 EVs.

However... the friendship berries are probably your best bet, as you can only eat one item from the Festival Plaza restaurant per day, and only if your Pokémon is not at maximum friendship. On the other hand, berries will lower a stat to 100 EVs if it's above that, and then reduce EVs by 10 each, so you only need a maximum of 11 berries to completely reset a stat.